# Mocha+Babel replaces class that extends array by array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, babeljs

I set-up a project with Mocha and Babel.

If I create a class that extends Array and call a method of this class on an instance, it works in console, but fails in the test with Mocha+Babel:

**It seems that the instance is perceived as an instance of Array instead of the extended class.**

The class:

```
class A extends Array {

    hello() {
        return "hi"
    }
}
```

The test:

```
import { expect, assert } from 'chai'
import { A } from 'a'

describe('A', () => {

    it('Should have a property', () => {        
        const result = new A();
        expect(result).to.have.property('hello')
    })

    it('Should be of the good type', () => {        
        const result = new A();
        expect(result).to.be.an.instanceOf(A)
    })


}
)
```

And the two errors I get:

- AssertionError: expected [] to have property 'hello'
- AssertionError: expected [] to be an instance of A

Any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Babel to transpile this to ES5.

`Array` doesn't behave quite the same as other constructors. There isn't really an equivalent syntax for doing this in ES5, because to some extent it was [not even really possible in ES5](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/). As such, what Babel generates in attempt to create equivalent syntax will not work the way you'd expect it to.

If you take a look at the generated code, you'll find this line:

```
return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (A.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(A)).apply(this, arguments));
```

At this point, `A.__proto__` will be `Array`, and the constructor was given no arguments, so this is calling `Array.apply(this, [])` and passing the result to the `call` argument of `_possibleConstructorReturn`.

In `_possibleConstructorReturn`, you'll find this line:

```
return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }
```

In most cases, calling `apply` on a constructor (invoking it without `new`) will return undefined. Thus, this function will return the `self` parameter, which is the `this` from the `A` contructor invocation.

`Array` does not behave like a normal constructor, however. If you invoke it without `new`, it will still return an Array. So what you get coming out of your `A` constructor is just a plain old array.

There may be ways around this, but Babel does not support any. To be honest, if you need your code to work in ES5, you probably shouldn't try to extend arrays like this. :\

What often works as an alternative is to write a simple class that stores an array as a property, with wrapper methods for the array operations you need. Say a `get` method to use in place of square bracket property access, a `push` that simply invokes `push` on the wrapped array.